# Having problems with WordPress 4.2.2 and Graphene theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

We're getting this warning on our site's main page.

```
Warning: Missing argument 4 for graphene_page_ancestor_class() in /homepages/33/d95215500/htdocs/DC-Canyon/wp-content/themes/graphene/includes/theme-menu.php on line 184
```

This was after I did all of the updates that it asked for. I don't have access to the file system directly; only the Dashboard. I've tried re-installing WordPress and uninstalling/installing Graphene.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix. I had to deactivate the "Ambrosite Unlink Parent Pages" plugin. It's back to normal now.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says,

graphene_page_ancestor_class() is a 4 argument based class/function and argument 4 ( required ) not passed trough the line **184** of **theme-menu.php** file.

It may an update problem ( framework and WordPress theme are not compatible well )

There is an also old topic about this error:
http://forum.graphene-theme.com/graphene-support/missing-argument-for-graphene_page_ancestor_class

Comment: As I stated though, I do not have access to the file system (via FTP or remoting in, etc). This means I cannot update individual files. All that I can do is use the Dashboard, which I don't think has an interface to the file system. Is there any other way to handle this?

Comment: I don't no if WordPress Theme editor detect this **theme-menu.php** file. If it detects you can copy the code of file and using an advanced text editor ( like Notepad++ ) and find line 184 and check why it's not sending arg 4. Then check find of graphene_page_ancestor_class function/ class and see what is the 4th arg used for and rewrite the code in **theme-menu.php** file(line 184).

Comment: I've found and installed WP-Filemanager, which lets me see some files in WP, but I don't see a graphene/includes directory. I have a feeling that this just allows management of files to be displayed as content, and doesn't give full access to all the WP files.

Comment: I managed to get the WP-Filemanager to work the way I needed by setting the Default Home location to "../wp-content/". I uploaded the file that was suggested by your link. Unfortunately, there was no change in the display. The new file also has the same function with the same number of arguments, BTW.

Comment: Access WordPress theme files from Admin panel -> Themes -> Editor ( then select "Graphene theme" ( from top left of editor ) and find **theme-menu.php** file.

Comment: Well, that was easier, thanks! However now I guess I'm venturing into WordPress programming, because now I need to understand who's calling this function and why are they not passing all of the arguments to it. I'll look around in here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/, I guess.